# Jquery Click Trigger not working for the label on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger click function for the first label (i'e tab1) after page loads, my html as follows

```
<div id="my-account-content">
<label class="tab" for="tab1">Maids</label>
<label class="tab" for="tab2">Housekeeper Nanny</label>
<label class="tab" for="tab3">Qualified Nanny</label>
</div>
```

Javascript works fine on click function, sample code below

```
$('#my-account-content label').on('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                ....
}
```

But when i try to trigger click function on page load it does not trigger the click function, code below

```
$('#my-account-content label:first').trigger('click');
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: It's much more reliable to extract the logic within the click handler to its own function and then call that function in the click handler and on load.

Comment: Are you triggering the click on $(document).ready()?

Comment: yes i'm doing that still it doesn't work

Comment: are you getting any error, because in the code you are not closing the () for "on" method

Comment: onlclick function works fine, what i want is on page load trigger label click

Comment: visit this link https://jsfiddle.net/smh1Ld7y/1/

Comment: Great! its working now! what i have done is i have placed trigger('click') above .on('click', function(e)) that's y it was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#my-account-content label').on('click', function(e) {
             alert($(this).html());
              
})

$('#my-account-content label:first').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-account-content">
<label class="tab" for="tab1">Maids</label>
<label class="tab" for="tab2">Housekeeper Nanny</label>
<label class="tab" for="tab3">Qualified Nanny</label>
</div>
```